# Php Class for manipulate text on image with GD

Tags: php

I looking for a class who can manipulate image with GD like center text, add border to a text, choose font...

Answer (score 1):

use this class

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6055-PHP-Draw-images-defined-with-CSS-like-properties.html

This class can render graphics in an image. It uses a CSS-like syntax to define the values of the parameters and options that describe each type of graphic primitive that the class can draw in the image.